# Token works in Postman but not in retrofit

Tags: retrofit

I have this kotlin class

```
@POST()
    suspend fun sample(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String,
        @Header("Accept") accept: String,
        @Header("X-Deliverit-Client") xDeliveritClient: String,
        @Url url: String,
        @Body payload: RiderQuestQuotiation
    ): Response<ResponseBody>
```

I call this like so:

```
var response = try {
            RetrofitInstance.itmsApi
                .sample(tkn,
                    "application/json",
                    "OrangeLabel",
                    "https://stg.doordash.deliverit.com.au/",
                    payload)

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }
```

Why is it that in postman, this token is accepted by adding, in the "Headers" tab, Key "Authorizatin" and Value "myTokenKey" but not in Retrofit using the code above?